# JavaFX - get a single ListCell from a ListView

Tags: listview, javafx

How can i get a single ListCell from a ListView in JavaFX? I would like to set the style of the ListCells one by one depending on some events.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a custom CellFactory. in the updateItem() method you can define your conditions and tell to your cell what element will be displayed depend on the condition.

see that for more details http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/listview-custom-cell-factories-and-context-menus/